# Dictionary with price and volume

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the highest price and also the highest volume.
This is what I am using but its only giving me the highest price. How can I find the record that contains both highest number for both?

```
Value = StockData.OrderByDescending(Function(u) u.Value.Price).ThenBy(Function(u) u.Value.Volume)
```

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Assume we know nothing about your problem (because we know nothing) and tell us everything that is relevant. The code you posted is not giving you any particular record at all. It's giving you the existing list but sorted. Stop leaving most of the relevant information in your head and put it in the question.

Comment: Do you mean return two records :- one record that contains the highest price and one record that contains the highest volume?

Comment: @WillWalsh just show 1 record that has the max value for price and max value for volume..

Comment: I would be storing this information in two separate variables, as they aren't related to a single record. Either way, you can use the LINQ function Max. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0

Comment: `Dim maxPrice = StockData.OrderByDescending(Function(u) u.Value.Price).First()` and `Dim maxVolume = StockData.OrderByDescending(Function(u) u.Value.Volume).First()`

Comment: this wouldn't work because it would display two different stocks.. I am trying to find the stock that has the highest volume with the highest price.. there are other stocks that have a really high volume with very low price and the other way around

Comment: your condition may never met

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to guess what your class looks like and the structure of your dictionary. I think what your are looking for is the largest dollar volume. I ordered the dictionary by price * volume. The symbols following the : in the message box string are formatting codes.

```
Public Class Stock
    Public Property StockSymbol As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Property Volume As Integer

    Public Sub New(Symbol As String, p As Decimal, v As Integer)
        StockSymbol = Symbol
        Price = p
        Volume = v
    End Sub

End Class

Private StockData As New Dictionary(Of String, Stock)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Add some sample data to the Dictionary
    StockData.Add("ABC", New Stock("ABC", 12.33D, 14000))
    StockData.Add("DEF", New Stock("DEF", 22.5D, 1050200))
    StockData.Add("GHI", New Stock("GHI", 19.45D, 15000))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DictionaryItem = StockData.OrderByDescending(Function(u) u.Value.Price * u.Value.Volume).First
    MessageBox.Show($"{DictionaryItem.Value.StockSymbol} - Price {DictionaryItem.Value.Price:##,###.#0}, Volume {DictionaryItem.Value.Volume:##,###,##0}")
End Sub
```